# .dump resulting in `File is not a database" with sqlite3

Tags: sqlite

I'm doing this in sqlite3 on my server:

```
> .output=../backup.sqlite
> .dump
```

It runs, its a 40gb db and after I finished I do this:

`sqlite3 backup.sqlite` and run `.tables` and I get the error "File is not a database"

Its same machine and everything so its not versioning issue.

Comment: The output of the `.dump` command is not a database. It is a SQL script

Comment: You're right. What's the proper way to create a clone of the database then? copy doesn't work because it changes as things write to the live db. Or how can I re-import this sql file to a new db?

Comment: See the `.read` [command](https://sqlite.org/cli.html#reading_sql_from_a_file)